# MVC 4 Parameter Name and Inheritance in View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I had try to search a solution to my problem, but I fail...

I have a model like this in my Asp.NET MVC 4 Web Application:

```
public class ModelBase
{
  public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
  public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}

public class InheritedModelOne : ModelBase
{
  public string PropertyThree { get; set; }
}

public class InheritedModelTwo : ModelBase
{
  public string PropertyFour { get; set; }
}
```

I have two actions in my controller:

```
public ActionResult ActionOne([ModelBinder(typeof(MyModelBinder))]ModelBase formData)
{
  ...
}

public ActionResult ActionTwo(InheritedModelTwo inheritedModelTwo)
{
  ...
}
```

My problem is when I use the name 'inheritedModelTwo' in my Action parameter of my ActionTwo, the property PropertyFour is correct binded, but when I use the name formData in my Action parameter of my ActionTwo, the properites PropertyOne and PropertyTwo are correct binded but PropertyFour. What I want to do is Bind correctly all my three properties of my InheritedModelTwo parameter of my ActionTwo method when I Post my form.

More informations:

1. the post comes from the same JQuery request.
2. the data coming from post are same in the two situations.
3. the only one diference in this issue is the parameter name of my ActionTwo.
4. put a different name in parameter of ActionTwo makes only the ModelBase properties to bind.
5. Sorry for my realy bad english.

Tks.

Comment: Could you post your view? Are you using @Html.TextBoxFor helper? It should do the trick for you. Another tip, use fiddler or Firebug and see what is sent to your controller.

Comment: could you put your whole view with jquery request ?Then we can test what you're telling. put it on your post.

Comment: Yes, I use @Html.TextBoxFor, remember my post data in the two situations is the same, when I change the parameter name of ActionTwo, diferent properties are binded without view changes.

Comment: Please, post the view with the jquery code...

Comment: You must need to do something special in your `MyModelBinder` class if you want something other than the base class to be passed into your first action.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly...

What you are trying to do is: to map/bind object that inherits from a base object, using base object type.

This will not work, because the inheritance works in one direction only.

..So you have to have the **InheritingModel** TYPE as the parameter type .

```
public class ModelBase
{
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}

public class InheritedModelOne : ModelBase
{
    public string PropertyThree { get; set; }
}

public class testObject
{ 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActionOne(ModelBase formData)
    {
        formData.PropertyOne = "";
        formData.PropertyTwo = "";

        // This is not accessible to ModelBase
        //modelBase.PropertyThree = "";

        return null;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActionOne(InheritedModelOne inheritedModelOne)
    {
        // these are from the Base
        inheritedModelOne.PropertyOne = "";
        inheritedModelOne.PropertyTwo = "";

        // This is accessible only in InheritingModel
        inheritedModelOne.PropertyThree = "";

        return null;
    }

}
```